# Discord.js Music bot joins then leaves

Tags: discord, discord.js

Whenever I type &play (name) the bot will join the VC that I am in then it will leave right after. It would start to play then leaves. I have FFmpeg installed and discord.js up to date. I also ran npm install @discordjs/opus ffmpeg-static yt-search ytdl-core  so that is installed too.
Here is the code:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
 
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
 
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
 
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
 
        if(validURL(args[0])){
 
            const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
 
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('leaving channel');
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)
 
            return
        }
 
        
        const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
 
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
 
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
 
        }
 
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
 
        if(video){
            const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No video results found');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your options of connection.play to:

```js
{seek: 0, volume: 1, type: "opus"}
```

You need to specify the stream type for Discord.JS

Comment: The bot stays in the vc now but no audio, error I am getting is: 

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: The compressed data passed is corrupted
    at Decoder._decode (C:\Users\socce\Desktop\Projects\Active Projects\HelexGames\Discord Bot\HelexTestBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\Opus.js:64:25)

Comment: Try to remove the filter from `ytdl`

Comment: I have fixed the error by running npm init again. But I'm not getting any audio. if the filter is removed that is when I get the error.

Comment: nope.... its all good though. I will figure it out or just not have this feature at all.

Comment: @Brayden You need to set the property **opusEncoded** to true  inside ytdl options